# How to use mongodb ObjectId value in where condition in yii2

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I have to count the students among different kind of roles.

ObjectId for the student role is `ObjectId("57ea5880b5ea6a0650005642")`.

```
public function count_allStudents() {
    $list = People::find()->select(['_id','roleid'])->where(['roleid'=>ObjectId("57ea5880b5ea6a0650005642")])->all();
    return count($list);
}
```

But it doesn't retrieve. The problem is `ObjectId` **type**.
How can I use the `ObjectId` inside `where`?

Comment: try add casting (string) - like this: 
```People::find()->select(['_id','roleid'])->where(['roleid'=> (string)new ObjectId("57ea5880b5ea6a0650005642")])->all()```

Comment: And you can use ```->count()``` instead of ```->all()```

Comment: ```ObjectId("57ea5880b5ea6a0650005642")``` - this is function and it's wrong.
Object creates by keyword ```new``` ```new ObjectId("57ea5880b5ea6a0650005642")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it something like this

```
public function count_allStudents() {
    $list = People::find()->select(['_id','roleid'])
                    ->where(['roleid'=> new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("$mongoId")])
                    ->all();
    return count($list);
}
```

Use `MongoDB` namespace.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php

Comment: Thank you!  How can I define `$mongoId`?

Comment: You can use your `id`, here in this case `"57ea5880b5ea6a0650005642"`.

Comment: It doesn't return value.

Comment: Does your object with that Id exist?

Comment: Yes, exist. Any other alternative solution?

Comment: Can you try this: `new MongoId('57ea5880b5ea6a0650005642')` ?

Comment: Do I need to define any `namespace` or something for `MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId` or `MongoId` ?

Comment: If I give some other attributes type of `string` or `int`, it works perfect. The problem is only with `ObjectId` type.

Comment: your answers were right. But I couldn't achieve namespace `MongoDB`. Because my file uses another namespace. That was the problem.

Comment: And I'm using Yii2.

Comment: In yii2 I couldn't access 2 namespaces in one file. That is the problem. but your answers are correct.

Comment: That's why I have posted another question.             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678794/how-to-use-two-namespaces-in-one-file-yii2

Comment: Looks like I have answered there as well. Can you accept any of these or both answers if those solved your issue? Or do I need any more help?